# What method to create, in order to delete the rows of information from the database?

Tags: java, row, sql-delete

This is my first time making an application and I am quite new with connecting the netbeans IDE to the MySQL database. I have a delete button in a Jpanel, and I want to be able to delete added rows. At the moment I can delete the added rows but they are of course not delete within the SQL DB which means they will remain there when I restart the application.

**This is what I have to delete the rows so far**

```
      private void removeProductBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    // TODO add your handling code here:
     DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) this.productTable.getModel();
      int[] rows = productTable.getSelectedRows();
      for(int i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
      model.removeRow(rows[i]-i);
 // If I highlight the rows and delte the, they are still in the SQL database.
 //How to remove the complete data from the row in the SQL database? What method to write?

    String sql = "DELETE FROM Product WHERE ProductID = ?";
```

**Below I have my query to put it inside the database. (so you know what variables I am using)**

```
    public ResultSet insertQuery(String query) {
    ResultSet result = null;
    try {
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate(query);
        result = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
    return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a '?' in your sql but you aren't using prepared statement.

For example's sake try:

`String sql = "DELETE FROM Product WHERE ProductID = " + rows[i]-i`

Question marks are used for prepared statements in java which (among other things) is used for sanitising inputs. Once you get the rest of your code working you should investigate it.

Comment: Thanks for that ;), adjusted it straight away.